# dojo exception:Object [object Object] has no method 'appendChild'

Tags: javascript, dojo

Hy,

i have some problems with dojo. I will migrate my scripts from 1.8 to 2.0.

This is my code:
I develop a addon for the new Univention Corporated Server 3.1. Univention has updated th dojo framework from 1.8 to 2.0 and i must migrate my code.

Under dojo 1.8 works my program very well.

```
define([
"dojo",
"dojo/_base/declare",
"dojo/_base/lang",
"dojo/_base/array",
"umc/widgets/Module",
"umc/widgets/ContainerWidget",
"umc/widgets/Page",
"umc/widgets/Form",
"umc/widgets/Grid",
"umc/widgets/TabContainer",
"umc/widgets/ExpandingTitlePane"
], function(declare,lang,array,Module,ContainerWidget,Page,Form,Grid,declare, lang,       array,TabContainer,_){
return declare("umc.modules.asteriskUser",[ Module ],{
    _buttons: null,
    _mailboxHint: null,
    _mailboxForm: null,
    _grid: null,
    _forms: [],

    buildRendering: function () {
        this.inherited(arguments);

        this._buttons = [{
            name: 'submit',
            label: "Speichern",
            callback: lang.hitch(this, function () {
                this.save();
            }),
        }];

        this._forms = [];

        var tabContainer = new umc.widgets.TabContainer({
            nested: true
        });



        tabContainer.addChild(this.renderPhones());

        tabContainer.addChild(this.renderMailbox());

        tabContainer.addChild(this.renderForwarding());
        this.addChild(tabContainer);

        this.startup();
        this.load();
    },
    renderMailbox: function () {
        var page = new umc.widgets.Page({
            title: "Anrufbeantworter",
            headerText: "Anrufbeantwortereinstellungen",
            footerButtons: this._buttons,
            closable: false,
        });

        var container = new umc.widgets.ContainerWidget({
            scrollable: true,
        });
        page.addChild(container);

        var noMailboxHint = new umc.widgets.Text({
            content: "Leider hat Ihnen der Administrator keinen " +
                "Anrufbeantworter zugewiesen.",
            region: "top",
        });
        container.addChild(noMailboxHint);
        this._mailboxHint = noMailboxHint;

        var widgets = [{
            type: 'TextBox',
            name: 'mailbox/password',
            label: "PIN-Nummer zum Abrufen",
        }, {
            type: 'ComboBox',
            name: 'mailbox/email',
            label: "Per eMail benachrichtigen?",
            staticValues: [
                { id: '0', label: "Nein" },
                { id: '1', label: "Ja, gerne!" },
            ],
        }, {
            type: 'ComboBox',
            name: 'mailbox/timeout',
            label: "Mailbox antwortet nach",
            staticValues: [
                { id:   '5', label: "5 Sekunden" },
                { id:  '10', label: "10 Sekunden" },
                { id:  '20', label: "20 Sekunden" },
                { id:  '30', label: "30 Sekunden" },
                { id:  '45', label: "45 Sekunden" },
                { id:  '60', label: "einer Minute" },
                { id: '120', label: "zwei Minuten" },
                { id: '180', label: "π Minuten" },
            ],
        }];

        var layout = [
            'mailbox/password',
            'mailbox/email',
            'mailbox/timeout'
        ];

        var form = new umc.widgets.Form({
            widgets: widgets,
            layout: layout,
            scrollable: true,
        });
        container.addChild(form);
        this._forms.push(form);
        this._mailboxForm = form;

        this._mailboxForm.domNode.style.display = 'none';
        this._mailboxHint.domNode.style.display = 'block';

        return page;
    },
    renderPhones: function () {
        var page = new umc.widgets.Page({
            title: "Telefone",
            headerText: "Telefoneinstellungen",
            footerButtons: this._buttons,
            closable: false,
        });

        var container = new umc.widgets.ExpandingTitlePane({
            title: "Klingelreihenfolge",
        });
        page.addChild(container);

        this._grid = new umc.widgets.Grid({
            moduleStore: umc.store.getModuleStore("dn",
                "asteriskUser/phones"),
            query: {
                filter:'*',
            },
            columns: [{
                name: 'position',
                label: "Position",
                editable: false,
                hidden: true,
            }, {
                name: 'name',
                label: "Telefon",
                editable: false,
            }],
            actions: [{
                name: 'earlier',
                label: "Früher",
                isStandardAction: true,
                canExecute: lang.hitch(this, function (values) {
                    return values.position > 0;
                }),
                callback: lang.hitch(this, function (id) {
                    this._grid.filter({
                        dn: id,
                        position: -1,
                    });
                }),
            }, {
                name: 'later',
                label: "Später",
                isStandardAction: true,
                canExecute: lang.hitch(this, function (values) {
                    return (values.position + 1 <
                        this._grid._grid.rowCount);
                }),
                callback: lang.hitch(this, function (id) {
                    this._grid.filter({
                        dn: id,
                        position: 1,
                    });
                }),
            }],
        });
        container.addChild(this._grid);
        foo = this._grid;

        this._grid._grid.canSort = function (index) {
            return false;
        };

        var widgets = [{
            type: 'ComboBox',
            name: 'phones/interval',
            label: "Klingelintervall",
            staticValues: [
                { id:   '2', label:  "2 Sekunden" },
                { id:   '4', label:  "4 Sekunden" },
                { id:   '6', label:  "6 Sekunden" },
                { id:   '8', label:  "8 Sekunden" },
                { id:  '10', label: "10 Sekunden" },
            ],
        }];

        var layout = [
            'phones/interval',
        ];

        var form = new umc.widgets.Form({
            region: 'top',
            widgets: widgets,
            layout: layout,
            scrollable: true,
        });
        page.addChild(form);
        this._forms.push(form);

        page.startup();
        return page;
    },
    renderForwarding: function () {
        var page = new umc.widgets.Page({
            title: "Weiterleitung",
            headerText: "Weiterleitungseinstellungen",
            footerButtons: this._buttons,
            closable: false,
        });

        var container = new umc.widgets.ContainerWidget({
            scrollable: true,
        });
        page.addChild(container);

        var widgets = [{
            type: 'TextBox',
            name: 'forwarding/number',
            label: "Weiterleitungsziel",
        }];

        var layout = [
            'forwarding/number'
        ];

        var form = new umc.widgets.Form({
            widgets: widgets,
            layout: layout,
            scrollable: true,
        });
        container.addChild(form);
        this._forms.push(form);

        return page;
    },
    setValues: function (values) {
        array.forEach(this._forms, function (form) {
            form.setFormValues(values);
        }, this);

        // disable the mailbox form if needed
        if (values.mailbox) {
            this._mailboxForm.domNode.style.display = 'block';
            this._mailboxHint.domNode.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            this._mailboxForm.domNode.style.display = 'none';
            this._mailboxHint.domNode.style.display = 'block';
        }
    },
    getValues: function () {
        var values = {};
        array.forEach(this._forms, function (form) {
            lang.mixin(values, form.gatherFormValues());
        }, this);
        return values;
    },
    load: function () {
        this.umcpCommand('asteriskUser/load').then(
            lang.hitch(this, function (data) {
                this.setValues(data.result);
            }),
            lang.hitch(this, function () {
                // hm...
            })
        );
    },
    save: function () {
        var data = this.getValues();
        this.umcpCommand('asteriskUser/save', data);
    },
  });
});
```

So and Chrome give me the following exception message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'appendChild' 
_1a86.buildRendering 
_11cd 
_abc.buildRendering 
_13a4.create 
_13a4.postscript 
a 
_11e4 
a 
(anonymous function) 
_c6 
_36 
_36 
_7b 
_37 
_7b 
_ee 
req.injectUrl._108
```

Have anyone an idea?

Thx for helping!

Comment: You should use the uncompressed dojo.js for development. It will make errors more usefull.

Comment: Okay i found the failure.
I should not declare "dojo" and other functions of dojo to.

But now i have a other problem.

Somehow is the worm in it today! -.- thx for help